# LWC: Call an Apex Method Imperatively

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have a simple button handle click function which calls the apex method and pass the params. However, if I pass the @track variable as param, then apex method is not getting called. If I pass the static value it is working fine. not sure what I am missing.

**Javascript Method: (Working)**

```
  handleClick(){
            window.console.log('inside button click: '+this.selectedOptionsList);
            const fLst = 'type';
            window.console.log('fLst: '+fLst);
            fetchPermissions({ sObjectName: 'Account', fieldList: fLst})
                .then(result => {
                    //this.contacts = result;
                    window.console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.error = error;
                });

        }
```

**Console Log: (Working)**

[image]

**Javascript Method: (Not Working)**

```
handleClick(){
        window.console.log('inside button click: '+this.selectedOptionsList);
        const fLst = 'type';
        window.console.log('fLst: '+fLst);
        fetchPermissions({ sObjectName: 'Account', fieldList: this.selectedOptionsList})
            .then(result => {
                //this.contacts = result;
                window.console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
            });

    }
```

**Console Log: (Not Working)**
[image]

**Dual-list box onchange Event:**

```
handleChange(event) {
    // Get the list of the "value" attribute on all the selected options
    this.selectedOptionsList = event.detail.value;
    window.console.log(`Options selected: ${this.selectedOptionsList}`);
    }
```

**Simple APEX method:**

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)    
    public static String getPermissions(String sObjectName, String fieldList){


        return fieldList;
    }
```

If you see in the log, both @track variable value and cont variable value are the same. However, I don't get the result if I pass the @track variable as you see in the log.

Comment: Show us how you declare `this.selectedOptionsList` and any code that can alter it.

Comment: @zaitsman, added the code where I am setting the value from onchange event from dual-list component.

Comment: So what is logged if you do `console.log(event.detail.value);`?

Comment: @zaitsman, expected value 'type' is printing in the log. I added the log file too.

Comment: sorry, then i literally don't get what is not working? your log shows `inside button click: type` in response to `window.console.log('inside button click: '+this.selectedOptionsList);`. What is not working?

Comment: when I use "this.selectedOptionsList" as a parameter to the apex method, apex method is not triggering. If I use 'fList' which is a static variable with the same value, apex method is firing and getting the result back.

Comment: my question is, if both the variable's value is the same, why the apex method is not firing? I have to use track variable as the user selects every time a different value.

Comment: What does it mean `apex method is not triggering`? Clear your network log in chrome, and click the button - is there an outgoing request?
Additionally, is APEX method marked `cacheable=true`? Show us the Apex method signature.

Comment: It is a very simple test method I am using it for this. It just returns the string what we pass. yes, cacheable=true. I will try clearing the network log.

Answer (score 3):

I found the issue, for some reason track variable value is set as an object instead of a string, that is the reason apex method is not accepting it.

I just stringify the object and sending it to the apex. It is working fine.

Comment: when using decorator annotated properties they will be wrapped in salesforce observable membrane (which is responsible for notifying about changes so the rererendering is happening) - thats the reason why they are an object